# Open links on the webview and Chrome browser

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a web view displaying a design template and there are several links inside the web view that I want to open with Google Chrome when the method is clicked inside the web view this new link does not open. But now, when I click on the link, it also opens in Chrome on the web. Help me please.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                launchURL(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My Method :

```
private void launchURL(String url) {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builderCustomTabs = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent intentCustomTabs = builderCustomTabs.build();
        intentCustomTabs.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        intentCustomTabs.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intentCustomTabs.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(url));
```

}

Comment: are you using android-custom tabs?

Comment: tabs? what means?

Comment: are u using this library https://github.com/saschpe/android-customtabs

Comment: using com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a link in your mobile browser, you can use this code

```
private void launchURL(String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to open the links in another webview or in chrome browser? or both?

Answer (score 0):

I Just Change this Value in my code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            launchURL(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```